# Generating PDF using JS PDF library

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I have a below JS method

```
generatePdf() {
        const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
        const doc = new jsPDF({
            encryption: {
                userPassword: "user",
                ownerPassword: "owner",
                userPermissions: ["print", "modify", "copy", "annot-forms"]
                // try changing the user permissions granted
            }
        });

        doc.text("Hi I'm Matt", 20, 20);
        doc.table(30, 30, this.contactList, this.headers, { autosize: true });
        doc.save("demo.pdf");
    }
```

it successfully downloads the PDF file but instead of downloading it, I am trying to display it on the web page using iframe if possible. I tried to do the same but it didn't work.
below is JS library that I am using.

https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You could create a blob url and use that to display the pdf on an iframe.

Instead of using the save method, use the output method as explained here: https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#output

```
const url = doc.output("bloburl");
```

Then you can use the url in an iframe src like below:

```
<iframe src='url'>
</iframe>
```

if you want to show the pdf in a new tab use:

```
window.open(doc.output("bloburl"));
```